# C++ Constructor of static member class not called

Tags: c++, constructor, static, winsock

I'm maintaining code that has a class called Receiver that includes a static class called WinsockManagement that performs the WSAStartup and WSARelease calls in its parameterless constructors. So in the .h file I have:

```
class CWinSockManagement
{
public:
    bool m_bInit;
    CWinSockManagement(void);
    ~CWinSockManagement(void);
};

class Receiver
{
     static CWinSockManagement wsaManager;
     ....
```

and in the cpp file I have the implementations of the constructors and the following declaration:

```
CWinSockManagement Receiver::wsaManager;
```

(I also tried:

```
CWinSockManagement Receiver::wsaManager = CWinSockManagement();
```

)

I'm expecting to reach the constructor of CWinSockManagement before the first instantiation of the receiver class, however my breakpoint in the constructor is never hit. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to automatically handle the WSAStartup and release sequence?

EDIT:
I had a look at the question [When and how are static data initialized in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923624/when-and-how-are-static-data-initialized-in-c) which was indicated as duplicate but I cannot see the similarities. This question is about the fact that the constructor of my static member is not called although it should be as this comment below pointed out: http://ideone.com/knx2p6

The program itself is running fine (it's "just" missing its socket communication). The class Receiver is not a static class. Depending on the config there can be 1 to n Receiver instances that are dynamically allocated. The Receiver class is in one compilation unit (also in one VS project), that is linked to a static lib. The instantiation of the Receiver instances is done in a different compilation unit (and VS project) that is linked into a DLL/.ax file. Does anyone see a reason that this might prevent static members from being initialized or their constructors being called?

Comment: Is the class Receiver instantiated by another static initialisation, and if so is it in another compilation unit?

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://ideone.com/knx2p6).

Comment: The class Receiver is not a static class. Depending on the config there can be 1 to n Receiver instances that are constructed and allocated via "new"

Comment: Further info: the Receiver class is in one compilation unit (also in one VS project), that is linked to a static lib. The instantiation of the Receiver instances is done in a different compilation unit (and VS project) that is linked into a DLL/.ax file.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `Receiver` is ever instantiated. Initialization of `wsaManager` should happen *before `main`*, or if it is defined in a DLL, at the moment the DLL is loaded. If this doesn't happen, your build process may be broken.

Comment: Well, I would also assume that something is broken, I just can't find out what and am trying to provide all the information I can.

Comment: If `Receiver` is defined in a static library, and nothing in its translation unit is ever referenced in the main program, the linker might not include `wsaManager` in the executable at all. If this is the case, you may have to instruct the linker to force its inclusion with [/INCLUDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3hwbhs.aspx) switch, or perhaps move the definition of `wsaManager` to another CPP file, next to something that is referenced in the main program.